# "Stream" an app?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, c#, streaming

Is there a way to "stream" an application on windows? This might not be the right place to ask this, but, is there a way to, say, stream something like Avast from one computer to another, and then have avast actually scan the client computer, not the host? I would preferably like to be able to do this free, and can program in C# if neccecary.

Comment: If this were possible, and I'm not sure that it is, doing an antivirus scan would be hell. You think the overhead from doing a scan normally is bad? Imagine that but over a network - slow, slow, slow!

Comment: im just chose that because it would be the best representation of the overall idea.

Comment: I've heard of something, but can't remember the name...It's not free though.

Comment: A stream is a one-way data transaction. Are you talking about literally streaming the application binary to the client computer and then doing all of the processing on the client? Because that's really just copying the application to your computer and then running it. Loading a virtual machine (or remote desktop) over the network wouldn't allow you to manipulate data on the client. Or perhaps you want to present your client system to the host and run the application on the client data from the host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible if you mean simply to bring the GUI from machine to another.

You can basically "fake" the XP mode like functionality and use Remote Desktop to just bring a single application.

This is similar to the Microsoft App-V environment... just "hacked" to a smaller environment!

It is far too detailed to write here, but please [read this blog post for more information](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117115603/http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2009/12/18/137048.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's done in large computer deployments, e.g. colleges and workplaces that don't value productivity high. It's probably an ugly way, it sure feels like it. It's probably a feature of Windows Server.

The better options are to install it on the remote computer, to host the files on the remote computer or to VNC in.